# creating Maps in Android. error in mainactivity.java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm Getting this error bellow  when I am trying to create maps in Android App

```
02-06 20:38:48.178 15186-15186/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agupta.routebus/com.example.agupta.routebus.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
       at com.example.agupta.routebus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ad.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.b(SourceFile:179)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(SourceFile:100)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzs(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1129)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2283)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
       at com.example.agupta.routebus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-06 20:38:48.198 15186-15190/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 280K, 6% free 7594K/8020K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 20ms
```

Comment: Did you see in you error message where it says `API key not found.` and what to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an API key to access google maps. First you need to get an API key from google developer website and save it in your String Resource file, and assign key in your Manifest file. Then only you can access google maps.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: <application
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2_API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyAcO7w•••••••" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

Comment: Please add your source code here, although the Error says you don't have a Key.

Comment: Add the Key inside <meta-data>                                                                                                                <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />                                                    String Resource file contains your API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

@prashant-gupta's answer is also valid. But you may be using a newer version of Maps for Android. If you check out the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_4_get_a_google_maps_api_key) page, step 4 indicates that you create a `google_maps_api.xml` that Android Studio has created. Once you've created an API key in the developer console, copy it to the xml and it should work out fine.